# wp_dropdown_categories not clickable

Tags: php, wordpress, list, children

Soo i made this Php code to list the subcategories of the current category.
It even checks if the category has children or not and if it does it lists them.

The problem however is that while it looks alright on my website. The links simply don't work. When i choose a subcategory from the list and click it nothing happens.

```
<?php
$args = array(
 'hierarchical' => 0,
 'orderby'=> 'title',
 'show_option_none' => 'Subcategories',
 'parent' => get_query_var('cat'));

$term = get_queried_object();

$children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
'parent'    => $term->term_id,
'hide_empty' => true
) ); 

if($children) {

wp_dropdown_categories($args);
}
?>
```

Here is a picture of the list on my website:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is with the changed base url and the added line in my $args
This sends me to http://www.papercraftplaza.com/category/animals/?cat=bear

```
<form id="category-select" class="category-select" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/category/'.get_cat_name($cat).'/' ) ); ?>" method="get">
<?php
$args = array(
 'cat' => get_query_var('cat'),
 'hierarchical' => 0,
 'value_field'      => 'slug',
 'orderby'=> 'title',
 'show_option_none' => 'Subcategories',
 'echo' => false,
 'parent' => get_query_var('cat'));

$term = get_queried_object();

$children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
'parent'    => $term->term_id,
'hide_empty' => true
) ); 

if($children) {


$select  = wp_dropdown_categories($args);
$replace = "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>";
$select  = preg_replace( '#<select([^>]*)>#', $replace, $select );
echo $select;

}

?>
<noscript>
        <input type="submit" value="View" />
    </noscript>
```

Comment: I changed your args and added 'name' => 'category_name' which modify the key of query variable from cat to category_name which WP uses. Then it should works. However it will not display dropdown since category is selected because of if($children) statement, I suggest to remove it or replace with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you've set no handler to submit/process the request.

I'll redirect you to official documentatiun examples, where you can find pure php or javascript soulutions.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories#Examples

If you need to explain something, please leave comment.

Comment: Changed it like the "Dropdown without a Submit Button using JavaScript (2)" example. however it is still unclickable.

See the code in the comment below!